# Sum of odd numbers is odd if each of the natural numbers is odd

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Prove that the sum of an odd number of natural numbers is odd if each of the natural numbers is odd.

Here's what I tried already but it didn't work:

$\sum_{i=0}^n i = 2n-1$ but when I use induction, I end up with $2(n+1)-1$ which would be an even number. Any suggestions?

Comment: Expand that expression and note that it ends in a "+1" with the rest having 2 as a factor.

Comment: "Sum of odd numbers" (in your title) does not mean "sum of an odd number of natural numbers" (which is the real question). Why are you writing $\sum_{i=1}^\infty i=2n-1$; what purpose does it serve? How are you trying to use induction? Why do you think $2(n+1)-1$ is even?

Comment: You may want to notice that 2(n+1)-1=2n+2-1=2n+1 which is odd.

Comment: @TheBluegrassMathematician you're right, I guess I forgot to distribute the 2 when I first tried to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{2k+1}(2n_j+1)=2\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2k+1}n_j\right) +2k+1=2\left [\left (\sum_{j=1}^{2k+1}n_j \right)+k\right]+1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

$a$ is odd $\iff a\equiv1\pmod 2$.

Comment: I never used mod before so I'm not sure what that means :/

Comment: It is the same as saying that $2\mid a-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of an odd number of odd numbers is the sum of several pairs of odd numbers plus an odd number.

The sum of a pair of odd numbers is even. [(2k + 1) + (2j + 1) = 2(j + k + 1)]

The sum of any number of even numbers is even.  [2k + 2j + .... + 2l = 2(k+j+...l)]

The sum of any even number plus an odd number is odd.  [2k + 2j + 1 = 2(k + j) + 1]

The sum of an odd number of odd numbers is the sum of several pairs of odd number (the sum of each pair is even; the sum of the several pairs is even) plus an odd number (which is odd, so when added to the even sum of several pairs of odd numbers yields an odd number) so the total is odd.

====

Or $\sum_{i=1}^{2k+1} (2j_i + 1) = 2(\sum_{i=1}^{2k+1}k) + \sum_{i=1}^{2k+1}1 = 2(\sum_{i=1}^{2k+1}k) + (2k + 1) = 2[(\sum_{i=1}^{2k+1}k) + k] + 1$ which is odd.